# KnockoutJS and ASP.NET MVC Form validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I know this topic is a little complicated. I'll try to keep it as simple as possible and add details as needed.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 website, which uses Web API for data access, and KnockOutJS on the front end to keep things humming along AJAX style.

Since I'm using Web API, instead of using the classic scaffolding from MVC, I have created a single management page for each Model that can perform all CRUD operations. Generally speaking, this works very well. A modal popup is used to enter information to create a new object. Updating is done "inline" in a grid.

When entering new information in the modal dialog, form validation works as expected. For example, leaving a field blank when the data is marked [Required()] will show an error upon submission.

The inline editing of the data is NOT validating however. In this case, I actually use two fields. A < span > tag is used to display the data. When the "edit" link is clicked the span is hidden and an < input > tag is displayed instead. This may have something to do with the proble. (The visibility is controlled via KnockOutJS. Editable() is a boolean)

```
         <div class="span3">
                <span data-bind="text: Name, visible: !Editable()"></span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { data_bind = "value: Name, visible: Editable()", @class="fullwidth"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
```

Note that the data involved (model.Name) is a KO observable. Not sure if this is a problem as well.

Has anyone had any experience getting these technologies to play nicely together?

Comment: Can you show us your new object creation code where validation works perfectly?